# ul li to align and justify on left side of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a list of option to the left of my div box.

at the moment this what I have:
[image]
html code:

```
             <div id="categorylist">
                <ul>
                    <li class="text-white">ALL <img src="images/all-   
                    ico.png"></li>
                    <li class="text-white">COMUNNITY DEVELOPMENT <img 
                    src="images/commdev-ico.png"></li>
                    <li class="text-white">SPORTS <img src="images/sports-ico.png"></li>
                    <li class="text-white">EDUCATION <img src="images/edu-ico.png"></li>
                </ul>
                
        </div>
```

css code:

```
  #categorylist{
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: table;
  }
  #categorylist ul {
      text-align: left;
  }
```

What I want to achieve is this:
[image]

Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: if you leave margin auto it will definetly put it in center. try adding more properties to the `margin` and also try using `grid` to achive the result.

Comment: `#categorylist ul {
      text-align: right;
  }`

Comment: Your code doesn't match the images, can you post the entire code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `categorylist ul`, `text-align:right`; instead of `left`

```css
 #categorylist{
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: table;
  }
  #categorylist ul {
      text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="categorylist">
                <ul>
                    <li class="text-white">ALL <img src="images/all-   
                    ico.png"></li>
                    <li class="text-white">COMUNNITY DEVELOPMENT <img 
                    src="images/commdev-ico.png"></li>
                    <li class="text-white">SPORTS <img src="images/sports-ico.png"></li>
                    <li class="text-white">EDUCATION <img src="images/edu-ico.png"></li>
                </ul>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for UL you have to give text-align right and for li list style none. I have tested in jsFiddle and it is working. Let me know if it is working for you.

```
#categorylist{
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: table;
}

#categorylist ul {
     text-align: right;
}

#categorylist ul li {
     list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #categorylist{
      margin: auto;
      display: table;
  }
  #categorylist ul {
      text-align: left;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change style** `text-align: left;` **To** `text-align: right;` in `#categorylist ul` **Class**

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            <style>
            #categorylist{
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                display: table;
            }
            #categorylist ul {
                text-align: left;
            }
            #categorylist li{
                list-style-type: none;}
            .image-list{margin-right:10px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <body>

        <div id="categorylist">
            <ul>
                <li class="text-white">
                    <img  class="image-list" src="images/all-   
                          ico.png">ALL
                </li>
                <li class="text-white">
                    <img class="image-list"   src="images/commdev-ico.png">COMUNNITY DEVELOPMENT 
                </li>
                <li class="text-white">
                    <img class="image-list" src="images/sports-ico.png">SPORTS 
                </li>
                <li class="text-white">
                    <img class="image-list" src="images/edu-ico.png">EDUCATION 
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </body>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it's work for you..